# how to get value for key from external object via getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

With a local array I can match a key to a submitted value like this:

```
var myArray = {
        "orange": "black",
        "red": "brown"
    };

var myKey = $("input").val();
var myValue = myArray[myKey];
alert(myKey + " is the new " + myValue); // outputs "orange is the new black"
```

How can I do this when the same array is externally stored? Not:

```
var myArray = $.getJSON('/files/colors.json');
```

or

```
$.getJSON('/files/colors.json', function(data){  
    var myValue = data[myKey];
    ...
}
```

Do I have to `$.parseJSON` even if my external array is in the correct format?

Comment: `$.getJSON` does *not* return you the object/array.  It returns you a promise object, so you can add callbacks.  You need to use callbacks to access the JSON data.  Does `var myValue = data[myKey];` (from your 2nd example) not work?  What's the question here?  P.S. `$.getJSON` will parse the JSON for you.

Comment: 2nd example -- data[myKey] -- doesn't work, unless I have a separate error. Can't do a jsfiddle for this because the json is on my domain..

Comment: what about getArray() ?

Comment: What's `getArray()`?  That's not a jQuery function.  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What doesn't work?  What happens if you `console.log(data)` and `console.log(myKey)`?  You get an error?  What is it?  P.S. You *don't* actually have an array here.  `{"orange":"black"}` is an object.

Comment: What does `/files/colors.json` look like?

Comment: Here's my example: http://bit.ly/19IL28o The value does not display. I'm trying to replicate this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/okonaq/1  the colors/json is the same object (not array, sorry) used in the bin

Comment: Your `$("#result").hover(` event isn't running because you forgot to wrap the call inside of `$(function(){})`.  jsBin probably does that for you.  Also, lose the `;` in your JSON file.

Comment: updated both, still not displaying anything: http://bit.ly/19IL28o

Comment: ok it's working with document-ready as the wrapper http://bit.ly/15AMCqX would still like to replicate the match of the input as in the jsbin ..

Comment: ok I think I have it http://bit.ly/13AWDm1 http://bit.ly/11I9UrX

Comment: with hover fixed http://gist.github.com/webstax/6158780

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.4+ will silently fail on the retrieval of bad JSON data so be sure that your data is tight.

Your second example should technically work. As a better example, try this:

```
$.getJSON('/files/colors.json', function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {

    console.log(key + ' : ' + val);

  });
});
```

You mention `Array` a lot. Is it worth mentioning that your data is better described as an Object?

Comment: thanks. I do now have data[myKey] working, with help from the above comments.